# Comparing $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\min(i^{-1},j^{-1})$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ni^{-1}j^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\min(i^{-1},j^{-1})$ and $b_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ni^{-1}j^{-1}$. I suspect $a_n/b_n\to\infty$ since the numerator and denominator feel like a divergent and convergent $p$-series respectively. I can't *quite* find the quick reduction to the $p$-series case to prove $a_n/b_n\to\infty$ though.

**Does $a_n/b_n$ converge or diverge?** Is there a fast trick I'm missing?

Comment: $a_n=2n-H_n$ and $b_n=H_n^2$ where $H_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n}1/j\asymp\log n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are divergent, though you're right about $a_n/b_n$. Let $H_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i^{-1}$ be the $n$-th harmonic number. For each $1 \leq k \leq n$, there are $2k-1$ occurrences of $k^{-1}$ in the sum $a_n$, hence
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{k} = 2n - H_n$$
while $b_n = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i^{-1}\right)^2 = H_n^2$, so since $H_n \approx \log n$, $a_n/b_n \to \infty$.